# In php, how to convert string value into an int?

Tags: php, string, variables, integer

```
$the_value = '42';
```

This is a string value.
Now I want to convert it into int and obtain:

```
$the_value = 42;
```

Comment: In almost all cases `'42'` would be treated the same as `42`, and converted automatically for you. So, what do you want to do that makes it important to make this distinction?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware for example `<?php declare(strict_types=1); 
$pos = '4'; 
echo substr('abcdefgh', 0, $pos);` would result in `TypeError: substr(): Argument #3 ($length) must be of type ?int, string given`. Not relying on type coercion, but instead ensuring proper types at all times, becomes a more pressing concern when developing with `strict_types` on.

Comment: @MarkusAO: It's not that I cannot think of countless examples where type is important, but the question was missing it. It could be an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where type is not the issue, but something else.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware right, based on available context (none), OP could just define an int to begin with if an int is desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert string to int in PHP, you can use Type Casting method or PHP built-in function intval().

```
<?php
$string = "56";
$int = intval( $string );
echo $int;
?>
```